# Search text in collection

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-collection

I will like to search for a string in a column A of a collection in Power apps and return the associate value from column B of the same collection

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a text box control with name `SearchInput`, a label control with name `myLabelControl` where you want to show column B value and collection named as `Customers`.

Then you can set the `Text` property of label control to:

```
First(Search(Customers, SearchInput.Text, "Column A")).'Column B'
```

This will show the value of Column B for first search result.